# how to use group by a derived table from outside of it

Tags: sql

why this statement doesnt work? I need to group by a derived table from outside of it, not group by in a derived table. the example below is just a simple sample of my real query. and this doesnt work either

```
select * from (select Value, Cash, max(Title) as title, [Status] 
from Campaign.Exchange) as tbl
group by tbl.Value, tbl.Cash, tbl.Status
```

here is the error : Column 'Campaign.Value' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Subquery is a stand alone entity logically speaking so everything needs to happen inside. Of course this means you don`t need a subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you will be able to use the `group by` from outside the subquery is to remove the aggregate from the subquery. There is no way around it honestly.

```
select Value, Cash, Max(Title) as title, [Status] 
from (select Value, Cash, Title as title, [Status] 
      from EkoCampaign.EkoExchange) as tbl
group by Value, Cash, Status
```

Comment: thanks but my question is how to use the group by outside of the derived table.

Comment: @smoothumut I edited per your comment, but I think you'll be disappointed.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. it worked on my query that group by was the only option --for my knowledge--. you saved my day :) 
I appreciate

Comment: @smoothumut No problem. Sorry it wasn't as smooth as you had probably hoped. :)

Comment: :) better than nothing